# Did Carl actually get raped?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, the-walking-dead

In final episode of *The Walking Dead* season 4 a big disgusting fat guy TRIES to rape Carl. We can hear the buckle of the guy and all, but we don't see him actually doing movements. So I'm a little confused regarding what happened. Please explain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just re-watched the scene in question to refresh my memory.
(*Warning: Graphic content discussion follows*)

It's true the fat man (whose name was Dan, apparently) was trying to rape Carl, but he never got far enough to begin the actual act.  We hear the sound of Dan undoing his belt buckle, but there's no indication he had time to pull his pants down, and Carl remained fully clothed for the entire scene.  Not even a ripped sleeve.  The camera is moving around a lot, but my sense of the scene is that there wasn't enough time for anything to have actually happened.

When the tables turned and Rick came to Carl's rescue, Dan was up on his feet in seconds, backing away with both hands raised.  There aren't a lot of shots below the waist in this struggle, but if Dan's pants were actually down, he would've been holding them up with at least one hand.

Answer (score 0):

He definitely wasn't raped, but I do think he was being molested.  The sounds you hear Carl make defiantly give the impression the attacker is doing something to him. And given the amount of time the attack is going on the man would've had ample time to overpower him. Plus Carl looks to be in pain and distress beyond just struggling.

As for the belt buckle it was most likely Carl's.  In the comics his attackers pull his pants off so it could be that was the intent here as the shows creators have said they originally filmed the scene to be more inline with the comics.

So no he wasn't raped, in all likelihood he was sexually assaulted in some manner though.

Answer (score 0):

In this scene, Carl, who is 14 years old and is a minor so he was too young- I might get this wrong

Carl is seen to be sleeping in the truck while Michonne and Rick were talking by the fire and were talking about what they never talk about and etc. They hear some cracking sounds in the forest and didn't go see what it was, they just looked in the direction from where it came from. Claimers came out of the forest and walk towards Rick and Michonne andJoe points a gun at Rick's head ad telling him that he "Screwed up"

Meanwhile, Carl is awakened by Dan at the window staring at him and Dan puts a knife up to the window. Soon Joe and his "Claimers start counting down to One Mississippi. Daryl pops up and stops Joe from counting to zero.

Daryl tries to make Joe and his "claimers" let Rick, Carl, and Michonne go and that they are good. But Joe brings up that Rick strangled one of his claimers to death in a bathroom so it meant that they were not good people and tells two of his claimers to "Teach him all the way" which meant "Beat him to death"

Terrified Carl watch them beat Daryl and is distracted which gave Dan a chance to pull Carl out of the car and hold him by the neck?> "I don't know what it was" Rick who notices that Carl got dragged out of the car, tries to get up, but is stopped because he is still held at gunpoint.

Carl is now whimpering. Dan who is holding Carl whispers in Carl's ear "Shhh" he said and did in a very disgusting way which sent a shivering tingle down Carl's body as he tried to get him out of his hands but couldn't. when Dan did that Carl turned his head and whimpered "No" as he knew what was about to happen

I'm gonna skip to the "Molested Part"

Carl is soon thrown to the ground by Dan. Dan gets on top of Carl and grabs his hands swaying them around like he was teasing him. Rick who watched Dan throw Carl to the ground is getting really angry. Meanwhile, Dan is telling Carl to stop squirming.

Other "Molested Part"

Soon, Carl is still struggling but is turned on his stomach and is held down and I could see he was beginning to Cry, Carl didn't want this. Soon you can hear Dan's belt unbuckle and he was about to rape Carl but is stopped so he didn't rape Carl I think he Sexually Assaulted Carl.